# Time Series chart interpretation

Tags: python, time-series, autoregressive-models

I was using Python to do a time series analysis. I observe the following pattern. Since the ACF cuts off at lag 12 and PACF tails off, does this mean I should fit a MA(12) to this series?

[image]

Well I actually fitted a MA(12) to the curve and I am getting the following:
[image]

Most coefficients are actually insignificant. Besides I don't quite understand how these nans come out.

Answer (score 0):

This may be seasonal data. Try first running a seasonal decomposition using statsmodels. Then plot the PACF and ACF of the decomposed data and try fitting a more parsimonius model (ie, lower number).